# Florida: under what statute if any, is a state agency obligated to respond to a petition?

Tags: florida, public-law

Are there any provisions or principles that require state agencies to respond to any petitioner, outside of proceedings as provided in the Administrative Act, and requests for public records?

By analogy, in France, the ["Code des relations entre le public et l'administration"](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/section_lc/LEGITEXT000031366350/LEGISCTA000031367312/#LEGISCTA000031367312) establishes certain rights and obligations regarding the interactions between individuals and government agencies

[From Chapter 119:](https://flsenate.gov/Laws/Statutes/2021/0119.07)

> 119.07 Inspection and copying of records; photographing public records; fees; exemptions.— (c) A custodian of public records and his
> or her designee must acknowledge requests to inspect or copy records
> promptly and respond to such requests in good faith. A good faith
> response includes making reasonable efforts to determine from other
> officers or employees within the agency whether such a record exists
> and, if so, the location at which the record can be accessed.

From [Chapter 120](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/STATUTES/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&Search_String=&URL=0100-0199/0120/Sections/0120.52.html):

> 120.52 Definitions.—As used in this act: (1) “Agency” means the following officers or governmental entities if acting pursuant to
> powers other than those derived from the constitution: (a) The
> Governor; each state officer and state department, and each
> departmental unit described in s. 20.04; the Board of Governors of the
> State University System; the Commission on Ethics; the Fish and
> Wildlife Conservation Commission; a regional water supply authority; a
> regional planning agency; a multicounty special district, but only if
> a majority of its governing board is comprised of nonelected persons;
> educational units; and each entity described in chapters 163, 373,
> 380, and 582 and s. 186.504. (b) Each officer and governmental entity
> in the state having statewide jurisdiction or jurisdiction in more
> than one county. (c) Each officer and governmental entity in the state
> having jurisdiction in one county or less than one county, to the
> extent they are expressly made subject